# HTML button in row not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var row = document.getElementById("table").tBodies[0].rows;
    $(function() {
      $('table td').click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id === "Sellbtn") {
          var sell = prompt("Input the amount you wish to sell");
          for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i += 1) {};

          //where the problem lies i guess
          row.cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(row.cells[4].innerHTML) - sell; 
          row.cells[6].innerHTML = +sell + +row.cells[6].innerHTML;


        } else if (e.target.id === "Deletebtn") {
          return false;
        } else {
          var ask = prompt("ادخل");
          $(this).html(ask);
        }
      });
    });
```

I have rows in a table that are loaded from the local storage since they've been previously saved. Each row has a sell button, which when clicked gives a prompt and asks the amount to sell. When the user enters a value, it should subtract the number in `cell[4]` from that number that the user entered, but what happens is that it only subtracts from `cell[4]` of the last added row, it doesn't detect which row of the button I'm clicking on. Putting this inside the `for` loop gives me nothing, not even an error.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your question.

Comment: parseInt to sell too.

Comment: Bottom right of your keyboard is the full-stop button, it's used between sentences.

Comment: What is `row`?  Is it just one element, or a collection of elements?  It's really not clear what this code is trying to do.  If `row` is a collection of elements then treating it as a single element can potentially reference the last in the collection, which would result in the behavior described.  The code also implies that `id`s aren't unique, which can cause unexpected behavior similar to what's described.  You'll want to debug this to find out exactly what is going on and where the behavior deviates from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop isn't doing anything.

Think you want to do something like the following but I'm not too sure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i += 1) {

    //where the problem lies i guess
    row[i].cells[4].innerHTML = parseInt(row.cells[4].innerHTML) - sell; 
    row[i].cells[6].innerHTML = +sell + +row.cells[6].innerHTML;

}
```

**Edit (ignore this)**

Just noticed `+sell + +` this piece of code. That'll need to be changed to something valid also.

Comment: `+{variable}` is a weird javascript shortcut that will coerce a string to a number. So that line is valid, its basically `(numeric)var plus (numeric)cell-value` (http://jsfiddle.net/1uhq8gfq/)